# Javascript - a form that can not be submitted for a minute after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have to create a form that can not be submitted for a minute after it has been submitted.

```
<form id="myForm" action="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath()
                    + " /upisKorisnika.html ")%>" method="POST">
    <table id='userInput' class="display" border="0" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:out value="E-mail: " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                <button onClick="submitform()">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And I gather that this issue would be solved in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit;
}
</script>
```

But how? Is there some sort of timer I could use?

Comment: Yes, you can use [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to make the form insubmitable for 60000 milliseconds (one minute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use a click event to submit.
2. Since the page is unloaded by the submit, you need to use a cookie to save the time and hide the submit button :

For example

[test page](http://plungjan.name/SO/hidesub.html)

```
<style>
#subbut { display:none }
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function() { // when the page loads
  var time = getCookie("lastSubmitted"),diff=0;
  if (time) { // we had a cookie
    time = +time; // convert to number
    diff = new Date().getTime()-time;
  }
  diff = 60000-diff;
  if (diff<0) diff=0;
  setTimeout(function() { // show in diff milliseconds
    document.getElementById("subbut").style.display="block";//show it
  },diff);
  document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit=function() { 
    document.getElementById("subbut").style.display="none";
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    setCookie("lastSubmitted",now);
    return false; // REMOVE THIS WHEN TESTED
  }
}

</script>

<form id="myForm" ...
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            <button type="submit" id="subbut">Submit</button>
        </td>
```

Here is a cookie script if you need one

```js
// from quirksmode
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a really good solution to me, but I can't make it work. The submit button does not show at all. I've even tried using this onload, but it doesnt show button:
window.onload=function() {
  
  setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById("subbut").style.display="";
  },0);

Comment: Missed a () from new Date.getTime() - I am testing something now. There is a logical error I will fix

Comment: you are really kind :)

Comment: Updated. Should work. See test page - let me know if you need the counter too - note the form does not submit for real until you remove the `return false`

Comment: I am still working on it, but I have a question, if I may. When we call setCookie method, we pass to it two parameteres, but in code snippet, setCookie is declared with three parameteres. How does that work?

Comment: The third is expiry date and there are even one more: path - but I assume you do not care if the user comes back in two weeks.  So for our needs two are enough